# Display output and also showing type error in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript2.0, typescript1.5

Actually it is printing the correct output in the UI. But in the console it is displaying a type error?...
How can I resolve this?

```html
<tr>
 <th scope="row">IP addrress</th>
  <td>{{deviceinfo['ip-address']}}</td>
</tr>
```

**ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'ip-address' of undefined**

Comment: Can you also share your controller file?

Answer (score 0):

this may happen in case **deviceinfo** was not assign **yet** as example you get the value by http request

you can use **ngIf** to display the deviceinfo information when it has a value  or truthy

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="deviceinfo">
   <td>{{deviceinfo['ip-address']}}</td>
<ng-container>
```

another option is to set deviceinfo property to empty object

*component*

```js
 public deviceinfo:any = {};
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could do:

```
<tr>
<th scope="row">IP addrress</th>
<td>{{deviceinfo?.ip-address}}</td>
</tr>
```

for the short form